Matrix Visual Total Row ONLY
I've been asking this for about eight years or so, but here it goes again:
How to display a Grand Total on a matrix without row subtotals?
The matrix contains 5 rows and 1 column. All measures in values. I don't want row subtotals.
Tried everything.
Row subtotals on

Per row level on for the 1st level (top) row

Everything is drilled down to the lowest level.

Layout is tabular


Thank you.

have you tried to turn off row subtotals？
